# Getting error when Django startup with runserver command

Tags: python, django

I have an django app that include sklearn, pandas and numpy libraries. I can run it without virtualenv however when I run it inside virtualenv I get his error. I am using Python3.8 on Ubuntu. I just want to use virtualenv to manage my packages easily. I re-installed packages in the virtualenv with PyCharm. My error include references to the joblib library too.

I cannot find any solution:

```
Matching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/turnusolwebproject/urls.py", line 31, in <module>
    path('factomat', include('factomat.urls')),
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/factomat/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/factomat/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from .parallel import Parallel
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .executor import get_memmapping_executor
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/executor.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .externals.loky.reusable_executor import get_reusable_executor
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .backend.reduction import set_loky_pickler
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 125, in <module>
    from sklearn.externals.joblib.externals import cloudpickle  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cloudpickle import *
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 167, in <module>
    _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
  File "/home/suat/Belgeler/github/turnusol/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 148, in _make_cell_set_template_code
    return types.CodeType(
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you may have run into [a known issue with Python 3.8 and cloudpickle following changes in PEP 570](https://bugs.python.org/issue36886).

It's not clear from [the cloudpickle Github repo](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle) whether it supports Python 3.8 yet, so a potential fix may be to use Python 3.7 in the virtualenv instead.